# Wanted delete an item on the recycleview.Once button delete clicked.The item deletes in the firebase database but in recycle view the item this exist

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

It deletes in the firebase database..but i have to login and logout to see the recycler view to get the item removed or change the activity layout such as back and click back the recycler view activity page to get the item cleared.
The item is there even if its deleted.What i shall do to clear the items in the recycler view after deleting it from database.

```
Context context;
List<Planner> MainImageUploadInfoList;


public RecyclerPlanner(Context context, List<Planner> TempList) {

    this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

    this.context = context;
    SharedPreferences userlogin = context.getSharedPreferences("userlogin",0);
    userid = userlogin.getString("UserID",null);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Planner directory = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

    holder.deldir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

            DatabaseReference planner = myRef.child("Planner");
            DatabaseReference planner1 = planner.child(userid);
            date = directory.getDate();
            locationid = directory.getLocationID();
            date1 = date.replace("/", "");

            DatabaseReference planner2 = planner1.child(date1);

            planner2.child(locationid).removeValue();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to notify the adapter abot that change?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your delete method -

```
MainImageUploadInfoList.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
```